# Google App Script URLFetchApp.fetch timeout

Tags: google-apps-script

How to overide max timeout in Google App Script using the URL Fetch Service?

```
function onOpen() {
  
  var url = "myurl.com/longprocess";
  var functionResponse = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Currently this is not possible

There is already a popular [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/36761852) for it. You can "start" it to increase visibility and hopefully accelerate the implementaiton.

Until then:

- Implement a `try...catch` statement and try the request again if it times out
- If the URL you fetch supports a callback argument, then you can deploy your script as a WebApp. You then ping your API to make the request, and once these are ready the API could send them back to your WebApp.